# grunt serve:dist not working with Backbone Generator RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using generator-backbone for Yeoman to generate my app. I'm using the RequireJS option for this. After generating, I can run grunt serve correctly. After adding some views and tempaltes, and successfully running grunt serve, I try to test the "dist" folder. I run grunt build, which works correctly, but when running the app from the dist folder I get several errors regarding some of the views files not loading, with require js.

I get 404 not found for these files and then an Script Error for RequireJS.

Is there something that needs to be added in the included Gruntfile so that the JS files for views are included in the process?

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: This is my Gruntfile, generated by generator-backbone:

http://codeshare.io/gjDWA

SUMMARY:
grunt serve works fine.
grunt build runs fine
grunt serve:dist or running the app frm the dist folder doesn;t work. Blank page with these errors:

http://screencloud.net/v/6O91
[image: Errors in console running from Dist folder]

Comment: Found the problem, and solved it. However, I'm not sure why this happens. The modules that are giving this error are loaded using require(). If I use define at the top instead, it works correctly and points to the correct file when using dist. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else encounters this issue, the problem is related to a property:
findNestedDependencies: true in the optimization configuration.

Cheers!